# How to get the changelog value of an LDAP directory

Tags: directory, ldap, ldap-query, changelog

I am using the following query to get the changelog value in an LDAP target :

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p portnumber -D "cn=Directory Manager,dc=system,dc=backend" -w password -b "cn=changelog""objectclass=*"
```

I am getting the following exception :

```
ldap_search: Naming violation
ldap_search: additional info: Naming context not found!
```

I am giving the right credentials, but still I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Is your value for baseDN "-b" a correct distinguished name (DN) ?